# Looking for all deltas in a column in Vertica

Tags: c#, sql, vertica

I am looking for a way to get all the changes in values to a particular column in Vertica using SQL.  Here's an example...

Date    Name    Location

**1/1/2014  Joe Atlanta**

1/2/2014    Joe Atlanta

1/3/2014    Joe Atlanta

**1/4/2014  Joe Boston**

1/5/2014    Joe Boston

**1/6/2014  Joe Atlanta**

1/7/2014    Joe Atlanta

**1/8/2014  Joe New York**

1/9/2014    Joe New York

(Sorry, wouldn't let me post the image)

I only want the rows where Joe made the initial move.  But I will need Atlanta twice, and some rows are duplicates, which are not shown in the example.

The actual data source is much larger, with hundreds of "duplicates" per person.(Imagine if there was a row for each street Joe was on that day in each city) Also, we are doing this for a million or so people in the same table.

I've resigned myself that I will most likely need to create a temp table, sort by name, then date, but I'm not sure how to get all the information I need without looking to a programmatic solution (writing something in C#)

Is it possible to say something like "When you current city does not equal the city one row up, grab that row"?  I don't think there is, but I'm kind of at a loss.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can achieve the task by using LAG function which can be used to get previous row data..

```
select * from TestTable1

;with cte as(
select date,Name
,LAG (Location) over (order by date) as PreviousLocation
,Location
,LEAD(Location) over (order by date) as NextLocation 
from TestTable1
)
select date,Name,PreviousLocation,Location,NextLocation
from cte
where PreviousLocation is null or PreviousLocation <> Location
```

I've used CTE(common table expression) in here.
and I retrieve Previous and Next Location for your reference.only use Previous Location for the Final Query.

result will be as follows.

[image]

you can select only Date,Name,Location from the CTE for your final query

Thank you

Comment: Just tested this, and it does exactly what I was needing!  I really appreciate the help.